# Airport Extreme keeps 'loosing' drives

Tags: macos, hard-drive, airport

I have an Airport Extreme with two WD 2Tb drives attached. The problem is that the router keeps loosing the drives. By this I mean the router disappears from finder and when I look at it in Airport Utility, the Disks tab is empty.

If I restart the router and check Disks again, they're back, the router appears in Finder and I can use the drives as I would expect.

Then sometime later, probably hours or days, I'll go to access one of the disks and the router will be missing from Finder again, the Disks tab empty and I'll have to restart it to get them back again.

Any ideas why this would be happening?

Comment: To connect multiple USB drives to an Airport Extreme you need to have a powered USB hub that is always on, do you have that? (Edit: Actually I may be wrong about that, but it may be worth giving a powered hub a try)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're right, @DaveNelson. My extreme's USB port can only power a single external HDD.

Comment: Ahh. That may be the problem. I'll have to give it a go. I've currently got a non-power hub in there.